# Cant get font: vw to work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Hi I've the following code as seen below. The webpage is divided into two clickable blocks MODELS1 and MODELS2. The text should resize as the window is resized.

Everything works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, however Internet Explorer is not recognising vw as text size and the text inside those two blocks in Internet Explorer is tiny.

I need to find a way to get Internet Explorer to recognize vw the same way as the other browsers so the font resizes the way it should when the window is resized. Can anyone help me out with this?

N.B I'm testing in Internet Explorer 11 but probably needs to work in 10 and 9 too if possible

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = 'menuChoiceContainer'>
            <div id='menuChoiceHeader'>
               <h1>
                 Management Tool
               </h1>
            </div>
            <a href="/tool/itool/index.php" id="choicelink1">
               <span id="link-spanner1">MODELS1</span>
            </a>
            <a href="/tool/ytool/index.php" id="choicelink2">
                <span id="link-spanner2">MODELS2</span>
            </a>
            <div id='menuChoiceFooterWrapper'>
               <div id='menuChoiceFooter'>

               </div>
            </div>
       </div>

    </body>
</html>

   #menuChoiceContainer {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
}

.option {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.option span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#choicelink1 {
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  font: normal 5.10vw 'Capital TT', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(../images/menuchoiceverticalsplit.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#choicelink2 {
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  font: normal 5.10vw 'Capital TT', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(../images/menuchoiceverticalsplit.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#menuChoiceHeader{
    display: table-header-group;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    font: normal 4.00vw/100px 'Capital TT', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(51, 102, 153);
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-image: url(../images/ebottomgrad.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: In what version of IE ?

Comment: 11 but needs to work in the other popular versions of IE if possible

Comment: IE has very spotty support for viewport units: [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw). One possibility would be to use a [polyfill](https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly)